# segmentation fault in linked-list in c programming

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

```
struct process
{
    int id;
    struct process *prev;
    struct process *next;
} *table;

struct process *Queue = NULL; 

Queue = (struct process *)malloc(sizeof(struct process));

struct process *curr = Queue; 


while (curr->next != NULL)
{
    curr = curr->next;
}
curr->next = (struct process *)malloc(sizeof(struct process));
curr->next = &table[0];
curr->next->prev = curr;
curr->next->next = NULL;
```

This is some of my code. I think my code doens't have any problem but, when I compile my code it returns segmentation fault. So I found two part which has segmentation error by debugging. One is `while (curr->next != NULL)` and the other one is `curr = curr->next;`. I don't know why these parts return error.. (This is C programming)

Comment: Both will fail if curr is NULL itself. Protect against that case.

Comment: Also, please provide a [mre] for questions like this. The context is always important.

Comment: After you have allocated a structure, do you remember to initialize the structure members? The `malloc` function only allocates memory, it doesn't initialize that memory in any way, its contents is *indeterminate* (and seemingly random/garbage).

Comment: Should I initialize structure by NULL after every `malloc`???

Comment: All pointers, yes. And all non-pointer values should be initialized to some default value as well. Or you could use `calloc` instead, which will fill the memory with zero bytes (which on normal PC systems is the same as `NULL` for pointers). What is the best solution for you depend on your use-cases.